# How to control ontouch functionality in android?

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I have put 10 images and put ontouch functionality on it but whenever I reached on 10th image it is still working and get back  to 1st image. 
I want to stop the ontouch functionality on 10th image or last image.

Anyone know about this functionality?

Here is Java code:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

float downXValue;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set main.XML as the layout for this Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Add these two lines
    LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    layMain.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this); 

    // Add a few countries to the spinner
    Spinner spinnerCountries = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_country);
    ArrayAdapter countryArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                new String[] { "Canada", "USA" });
    spinnerCountries.setAdapter(countryArrayAdapter);

}

public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    // Get the action that was done on this touch event
    switch (arg1.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
            downXValue = arg1.getX();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
            float currentX = arg1.getX();            

            // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
            if (downXValue < currentX)
            {
                // Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
                 ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
                 // Set the animation
                  vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out));
                  // Flip!
                  vf.showPrevious();
            }

            // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
            if (downXValue > currentX)
            {
                // Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
                ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
                 // Set the animation
                 vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_in));
                  // Flip!
                 vf.showNext();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // if you return false, these actions will not be recorded
    return true;
}
```

}

here is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    >

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">  




         <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:background="@drawable/eea" 
            android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="1dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:background="@drawable/ef" 
            android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="1dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:background="@drawable/eg" 
            android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="1dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:background="@drawable/eh" 
            android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="1dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout> 


    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

I had use View flipper in my code and then add the images on it.

Comment: Where is the image thing u were talking of..?

Comment: sorry i post the wrong xml file now i post the rightone you can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @user552027 i also had the same problem in my application i have got solution for this you can check this link
```

[How can i control images in viewflipper in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354398/how-can-i-control-images-in-viewflipper-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

On 10th image's `onTouch()` method `setFocussable("false");` and `setFocussableInTouchMode("false")` for all other images.. only way i guess..

Comment: I can show you my code then you will told me where i put this. The code is in the question

Comment: I can show you my code then you will tell me where i have to place this